# How to direct my release/deployment based on web.config file in TFS 2015

Tags: tfs, azure-pipelines, tfs-2015, continuous-deployment

I've got an .Net application in TFS 2015. I've configured CI and works fine. Now i'm configuring CD for the application. Depending on a variable in web.config file, i need to choose my deployment path.

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="ApplicationID" value="1" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Eg:

```
if ApplicationID= 1 then my deployment path should be server1:\Deploy\abc    
if ApplicationID= 2 then my deployment path should be server1:\Deploy\xyz    
if ApplicationID= 3 then my deployment path should be server2:\Deploy\mns    
if ApplicationID= 4 then my deployment path should be server2:\Deploy\bvc
```

How to configure this scenario?

Deployment task - Windows Machine File Copy. Please suggest if task change is needed.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can add a PowerShell task that read the value from the XML, then create a new environment variable with server path depends on the app id, in the deployment task use this variable:

```
[xml]$xmlObject = Get-Content "path/to/xml/file"
$appId = $xmlObject.configuration.appSettings.add.Where({ $_.key -eq "ApplicationID" }).value
$serverPath = ""
switch ($appId)
{
    1 { $serverPath = "server1:\Deploy\abc" }
    # Add here all the values
}

# Create the new variable:
Write-Host "##vso[task.servariable variable=serverPath]$serverPath"
```

Now in the deployment task use the variable `$(serverPath)`.

Comment: Can you guide me on powershell task [code to be written in the task]

Comment: Sorry, i mean - Code to be written in the deployment task to use Variable `$(serverpath)`. Do we need to use variables under configuration section of Release or anyother way around

Comment: What is your deployment task? Can you share your release pipeline?

Comment: I'm Using Windows Machine File Copy task for Deployment. I've update the screenshot in the question.  Please suggest if task change is needed.

Comment: So the machine and the path are different, just create 2 variables (one for machine and one for path) and use them (in the copy task)

Comment: I'm trying to use - Run Inline PowerShell task to accomplish this. How to store $serverPath as variable for my next task/variables section. Is any other task preferred? Please suggest